# Blank split string in java String.split

Tags: java, regex, split

My goal here is to extract character from such string

```
(B,C) (D,E) (A,B)
```

to String array `[B,C,D,E,A,B]` with `split` method.

Regex string that I have used is `"\\(|\\)|,"`

And I get a result with `[B,C, ,D,E, ,A,B]`

I have absolutely no idea why there are blank characters in the result array.

```java
String[] tokens = str.split("\\s");
for(String token : tokens) {
   token.charAt(1);
   token.charAt(3);
}
```

This could be another answer, but I just want to know what I am missing from `split` method and regex.

Comment: Since there is a `(` at the start and you are splitting on `(` there will be an empty string at the start of resulting array.

Comment: @anubhava adding `\\s` on regex yielded way different and wrong result. Are there any another way to add blank space for regex in split method?

Comment: @user16320675 That is a one lovely way to solve this problem. Thanks :)

Comment: @jadon: Have posted an answer below for Java 8

Answer (score 1):

What you want here is a regex find all.  One straightforward approach is to use a formal `Pattern` and `Matcher`:

```java
String input = "(B,C) (D,E) (A,B)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(([A-Z]+),\\s*([A-Z]+)\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();

while (m.find()) {
    matches.add(m.group(1));
    matches.add(m.group(2));
}

System.out.println(matches);  // [B, C, D, E, A, B]
```

Another approach, if you insist on using a string split, would be to first preprocess the string of tuples into a space separated list:

```java
String input = "(B,C) (D,E) (A,B)";
input = input.replaceAll("\\(([A-Z]+),\\s*([A-Z]+)\\)\\s*", "$1 $2 ");
String[] parts = input.split(" ");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));  // [B, C, D, E, A, B]
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comment that since there is a `(` at the start and you are splitting on `(` there will be an empty string at the start of resulting array.

You can use this Java 8 stream based code to get rid of empty strings:

```sh
String str = "(B,C) (D,E) (A,B)";
String[] tokens = Arrays.stream(str.split("[(),\\s]+"))
   .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).toArray(String[]::new);

//=> [ "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B" ]
```

<kbd>[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/G06Cwd)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "(B,C) (D,E) (A,B)";
    String[] tokens = str.replaceAll("[(),\\s]+", " ").trim().split(" ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
}
```

output:

```
[B, C, D, E, A, B]
```

Comment: `trim` might be useful when there is blank at the start and end of given string. Thanks!